# How to Parse through a URL without opening the web page in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am getting a URL from the active web page after injecting the code from contentScript.js. Now I want to parse through the webcontent of that URL and get some elements in that without opening the web page of thet URL. Is it possible?? How??

//contentScript.js

here im getting a url like "www.facebook.com". Now I want to crawl the web page and get some elements in that page using that URL without opening that URL in same/other tab.

I tried using Yahoo Query language getting authorization error:

{

.......

"error": "Redirected to a robots.txt restricted URL: https://www.facebook.com/"

}

Answer (score -1):

Sure - if you mean, without opening it in the browser... in either the same tab/or another tab - in other words, without the user knowing...

If so, you simply need to grab it using AJAX ("in the background")

Add your code to the question, and I will add in an example.

You should also check out **artoo.js** which is a pretty powerful JavaScript library for scraping other web pages that ALSO COMES as an extension.  You'll have to read through the documentation at the URL below, but you should be able to use their extension to modify your:

http://medialab.github.io/artoo/chrome/

Comment: Not _always_ possible, e.g. if the page has dynamic elements.

Comment: dynamic elements generated from script / CSS that load with/after the page? I've updated the answer.. give me my -1 back :-)

Comment: hehe... sorry... browser issues :-)

Comment: this answer is incomplete. does not mention anything about dinamic pages that load parts with ajax, or pages that might require authentication.

Comment: Flak DiNenno: Thanx for the reply :) You can check my Updated question